# Resolve /.. in path in PHP

Tags: php, directory

my PHP script is executed in `/home/pi/parentfolder/childfolder/index.php`. My script has the task to check wether the path exists (or if it is renamed). To check if it is present, I use `is_dir(__DIR__ . "/../../parentfolder/")`. If its present, I would like to output the path. Problem is that the path is `/home/pi/parentfolder/childfolder/../../parentfolder/` and the `/..` parts are annoying me. I don't wanna set the path static.

How to resolve the path so that the `/..` are removed and the path is `/home/pi/parentfolder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `realpath()` to achieve this (as long as the path exists)

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Answer (score -1):

PHP function: [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

```
string dirname ( string $path [, int $levels = 1 ] )
```

> Given a string containing the path of a file or directory, this function will return the parent directory's path that is levels up from the current directory.

Example of usage:

```
$dir = dirname(__DIR__, 2);
is_dir($dir . '/parentfolder/'); // should return true
```